# VS Code, remove the dotted border around the hovered item of the suggestion pop-up (IntelliSense)

Tags: visual-studio-code

With the following "settings.json", I could change the colours of the suggestion pop-up like the screenshot. The problem is that I could not remove the dotted-line around the hovered item. How can I remove it?

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#351407",
    "editorSuggestWidget.selectedForeground": "#f1f0dc",
    "list.hoverBackground": "#555555",
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see these dotted lines on Windows Is that what you are using?

Comment: @TimothyG. I am using the "high contrast" theme on Windows.

Comment: change `focusBorder` but this also changes a lot of other colors like the search text highlight, type `console.l`

Comment: @rioV8 It seems that I can only change the colour of the border, not the focus background? I mean, If I set `focusBorder` to black to hide the dotted border of the screen above, it also make the current tab rectangle on the tab bar above, and the hover border when I place the mouse above one of the buttons on the left. So, if `focusBorder` is the only thing, I think one can say that removing the dotted border is practically impossible.

Comment: I use the light theme and they nowhere show a focusborder, so they might set it to transparent and use other colors/settings to get an effect

Comment: @rioV8 I had tried to find something like 'focusBackground', but that kind of thing did not exist. Maybe I should look into the source code of the Light theme to see how it sets the background colours for focus and hover.